# INNER JOIN BIZZARE ERROR

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, inner-join

I'm building a query to pull data from mutliple tables to generate a report, but the INNER JOIN's give me a "Syntax error in JOIN operation." and highlight the ON keyword.  I suspect this is a simple problem, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  please help.

```
SELECT
    [_MAIN_].ID,
    [_MAIN_].Project,
    [_MAIN_].Client,
    [_MAIN_].Description,
    [_MAIN_].[Sub Project],
    Tasks.Task
FROM ( [_MAIN_]
    INNER JOIN (Tasks ON [_MAIN_].Tasks = Tasks.ID))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parenthesis look off.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    m.ID,
    m.Project,
    m.Client,
    m.Description,
    m.[Sub Project],
    t.Task
FROM [_MAIN_] as m
  INNER JOIN Tasks as t 
    ON m.Tasks = t.ID
```

Comment: sorry but it did not work.  the error is now just "Type mismatch in expression"

Comment: @JamesWilson But that isn't a syntax error - that's telling you the two columns you are trying to compare are different datatypes.

Comment: @JamesWilson Solving the syntax error revealed an additional error. I am going to guess that `[_MAIN_].tasks` is not meant to match `Tasks.ID`. Perhaps you have a column called `[_MAIN_].TaskID` to join on instead?

Comment: @Bridge, I thought that might have been the ticket, but they are both "Long Integer" type

Comment: @JamesWilson Is there more to your query than what you have shown so far, such as a `where` clause?

Comment: this is my build from the start, and [_MAIN_].Tasks is directly related.  I have them both as the same datatype, the relationship is set and it works perfectly fine in the form entry pulling from the tasks table to create a combo box.  this is why i'm so lost

Comment: if it helps and since this database is still only holding test data I can upload  it for anyone that wants to download and take a look

Comment: @JamesWilson Sure, I'll take a look.

Comment: heres the database as well as a text file with the original attempt at the SQL for the report.     https://www.dropbox.com/s/jj842k30gsbv8p2/DatabaseDesign.zip?dl=0

Comment: The only place for a type mismatch is on `m.tasks = t.id`.  Try inverting the two values `t.id = m.tasks` so implicit casting goes the other way.

Comment: @JamesWilson I have no error when running the query in my answer on your database. Sometimes Access goes wonky once it has encountered an error in an attempted query. Try creating a new query and using the above code.

Comment: wtf..... well that code worked when i closed and re-opened ACCESS.  now i need to expand it to be the complete query.  thanks!